# .html() not working in jquery to show table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i have table to show with records and i m showing table using jquery's method .html() but i m not being able to get the output for that. Please help..Here is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#dateButton').click(function(){
var val=$('#datetextboxid').val();  
    $.ajax({
        url : 'T_Oms_08_D_Delivery_Servlet',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(json) {
            var dateTableRow = "";
            var headerOfTable="";                       
            $.each(json, function(key, value){
                if(value.date==val){
                    dateTableRow=dateTableRow
                    +"<tr bgcolor='#F0F8FF'>"
                    +"<td>" + value.omsOrderId+ "</td>"
                    +"<td>" + value.orderId+ "</td>"
                    +"<td>" + value.customerId+ "</td>"
                    +"</tr>";
                }
            });
            headerOfTable=headerOfTable
            + "<tr bgcolor='#6495ED'>"
            +"<td>Order DB ID</td>"
            +"<td>Order ID</td>"
            +"<td>Customer ID</td>" 
            +"</tr>";
            $("#form").html(headerOfTable+dateTableRow).fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(1000);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            for (key in xhr)
                console.log(key + ":" + xhr[key]);
        },
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            //alert("The request is complete!");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

'datebutton' is the id of the button.where i am supposed to click and see the table.
Here is my html code

```
<div id="divOfDateTable">
Search:<input type="text" id="datetextboxid"><button id="dateButton">Search</button>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1"  border="1" style="empty-cells: hide;" width="2800" >
<tbody id="form">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste HTML code

Comment: Is `#form` the ID of a table element?

Comment: Is your problem that your table is not displaying the right content or did I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: @Archer #form is id of the table element where i m gonna show the table

Comment: @Jonas table is not displaying.But when i do ".on('change',function())" instead of ".click(function())" table displayed.So what could be the possible solution for that...

Comment: Can you post the markup for the button and the table?

Comment: @Rohitkolhe what if you use .on('click', function());

Comment: @Jonas not displaying the table using .on('click',function())

Comment: Guys i want to tell you one more thing that for checking the flow if the code i put the alert inside the if() block in each function so..the alert was successfully prompted on browser.So the only concern is table is not being displayed.

Comment: as @Archer already asked, can you post the HTML for the table and the button? It can help us understand better why your code isn't working.

Comment: Close your input tag to stop the change event firing from the button click... `<input type="text" id="datetextboxid" />` <-- note the closing slash

Answer (score 0):

from a quick look, try the velow code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dateButton').click(function(){
    var val=$('#datetextboxid').val();  
        $.ajax({
            url : 'T_Oms_08_D_Delivery_Servlet',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(json) {
                var dateTableRow = "";
                var headerOfTable="";    
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
                        if(value.date==val){
                            dateTableRow+="<tr bgcolor='#F0F8FF'>"
                            +"<td>" + value.omsOrderId+ "</td>"
                            +"<td>" + value.orderId+ "</td>"
                            +"<td>" + value.customerId+ "</td>"
                            +"</tr>";
                        }
                    });
                    headerOfTable+= "<tr bgcolor='#6495ED'>"
                    +"<td>Order DB ID</td>"
                    +"<td>Order ID</td>"
                    +"<td>Customer ID</td>" 
                    +"</tr>";
     $("#form").html(headerOfTable+dateTableRow).fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(1000);
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                for (key in xhr)
                    console.log(key + ":" + xhr[key]);
            },
            complete : function(xhr, status) {
                //alert("The request is complete!");
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

**Reason** : reason might be for not working is below these two lines -

```
if(value.date==val){
                    dateTableRow=dateTableRow
                    +"<tr bgcolor='#F0F8FF'>"
}
headerOfTable=headerOfTable
"<tr bgcolor='#6495ED'>"
```

You are assigning empty variable to it's own rahter to attach the next line of string. I changed  `dateTableRow=dateTableRow` to  `dateTableRow= +"<tr bgcolor='#F0F8FF'>"` and `headerOfTable=headerOfTable` to `headerOfTable+="<tr bgcolor='#6495ED'>"`. Hope this will be helpfull.

Comment: what are you trying to say i cant got it...its the same code i think what i have posted..

Comment: added the description. Reason for being downvote ? @Rohitkolhe

Comment: But Nalin i dont think that will be the reason for notgetting table becuase same code was giving output for .on('change',function()) event. And if you want to say about null variable then i have define those two variables outside each function so there is no chance of getting empty string in html().If those could have in each function then there would have been chances of being empty strings in html()